how to fix list view is cut from bottom in dialog when keyboard is open flutter
In a Dialog when a list is shown and the keyboard is open for search the list cant be scroll to the last index and it looks like the list is cut from bottom. here you can see in this video if I open kyboard and search the remaining values in list cant be scrolled unless the keyboard is open.
https://mega.nz/file/HB4VkbqR#kCaZliXx5HPLKUCsr9oeuxOY1n4WBxlQhkzhZfkJE6E

I guess the root widget in the Dialog is Scaffold, try to set resizeToAvoidBottomInset false

I don't know about your code but you can try these methods:

Wrap Your List in a SingleChildScrollView.
Use MediaQuery to Adjust the Height.
Adjust resizeToAvoidBottomInset


Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true );


Use DraggableScrollableSheet

You can try any of these and then check. If you want sample code so I will provide you some example with it.
